# Deciding if x-y is 0 or negative without using conditionals

Tags: math

So,

My friend has come up with this interestng question, that is, given two numbers `x` and `y` deciding whether their difference: `x-y`is 0 or less without using any conditionals. The code should return 0 if they are 0 or less, or the result of the subtraction otherwise.

My attempt (In Pseudo-Java):

```
try {
Math.log(x-y);
} catch(Math.Error e) {
return 0; }

return x-y;
```

However, I have a feeling that Java exception handling or log method may use conditionals at some point, which in a way would be cheating.

Thoughts? :D

Comment: why not take the maximum between the subtraction and zero?

Comment: @WooiKentLee I was going to mention that, but I'm pretty sure the Max function would use a conditional. I assume he wants to have no conditionals whatsoever. I don't know why, but that's what it sounds like. **EDIT**: Although if that was the case, then I'm sure try-catches use conditionals too... `max(0,x-y)` would then fit the spec.

Comment: Wrong site. This might be on-topic on [so]

Comment: Could also do some math using the signum or abs methods. Either way, this question doesn't really fit in codegolf.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! All questions on this site must be programming contests with an objective winnings criterion (or tips questions for such programming contests). Unless you specify how the winner is going to be picked (e.g., code-golf is shortest code in bytes, atomic-code-golf code in operations), this question will have to get closed.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this, assuming the integer type is signed and has 32 bits:

```
~((x-y) >> 31) & (x - y)
```

this shifts the sign bit of the difference right by 31 places, generating either 0 if x - y is positive or -1 if the result is negative. This inverted is anded with x - y to get 0 if x - y is negative, x - y otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

There is a common misconception that comparison operators (e.g., `>` or `<`) somehow involve conditionals.

For most if not all architectures, this is not true. On x86, [CMP](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Comparison_Instructions) sets the sign flag simply to most significant bit of the difference of `x` and `y`, so no conditionals are involved.

In C, Python and many other languages (but, notably, not Java), you can use

```
(x > y) * (x - y)
```

which will be **x - y = 1 * (x - y)** if **x > y** and **0 = 0 * (x - y)** if **x ≤ y**.

Comment: Note: Since the OP's example is in "pseudo-java", you might want to point out that this won't work that well in *actual* java. `(x>y)` is a boolean type, and can't easily be multiplied without adding a conditional.

Comment: @Geobits: I don't know Java, so I had no idea. Is there no way to cast a Boolean to an integer type?

Comment: Well you can't do a straight cast (`(int)mybool` doesn't compile). Typically I use a ternary like `x>y?1:0`, but I can't see how that wouldn't count as a conditional here. There may be a builtin to do this, but it would probably use an internal conditional.

Comment: Jupp, and on x86 you could use this sequence of instructions to compute the desire result, assuming `ecx` contains `x`, `ebx` contains `y` and the result is supposed to go to `eax`: `xor %eax,%eax; sub %ecx,%ebx; sets %ebx,%eax`